# ES6 Change object values inside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have angular controller, which injects an array:

```
class a{
    constructor(items){
        this.items = items;
        this.items[0].name = "abc";
    }

    edit(){
        this.items[0].name = "abc";
    })
}
```

If I will change the value of one item in this array, inside the constructor, it will change the value of the item in the original array.

If I change the value inside the edit method, it will not change now in the original.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: `this` depends on how `edit` is called

Comment: It is called from angular ng-click

Comment: Shouldn't edit be inside the class?

Comment: Obviously somewhere else a new value is assigned to `this.items`. `var _this = this` doesn't matter.

Comment: In Angular promises, the data is in `res.data`, so you want `res.data.name`

Comment: I am sure your class definition is perfectly fine and should work. The problem is either that your `res.name` property is the same as the old value for that property, so the change is happening but you're not observing it, or, you're not calling the edit method right on the instance but instead you're calling it by reference.

var instance = new a(someItems);
var edit = instance.edit;
edit() // here this will not refer to the class instance anymore

Comment: @Alnitak it is for the example, it doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how `this` works in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/2135910). @user3712353 Please either review the excelent answer from there and make sure you know how `this` works in javascript, or provide more informations on what is wrong with your code, what is the error you're receiving or how can it be reproduced.

Comment: Hi. I've seen the answer. Anyway, ES6 claims that arrow function gets the parent scope. I guess it copies the scope and not reference to it, thats why I cant change the original value from the arrow function. Hope someone will know the answer.

Comment: You already have the answer. The problem is not this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use angular then you should use `angular.copy` or `angular.extend` to assign `items` in `_this.items` without reference

```
var _this = this
_this.items =angular.copy(items);
```

Comment: Already tried it (to the object, not to the whole array), didn't work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem the OP's author is facing. Also, when assigning a value to a variable depends on the usage context.  You don't have to copy the input every time to assign it to some class property. It's not even a "considered" best practice, so this answer doesn't address the problem at all.